# Need help in Creating Custom Audit Log for Custom Object

Tags: trigger

We all know that field value change made to any custom object record can be tracked in "History" for that record by enabling field tracking. But I have got a requirement where whenever a record(Proposal) is created/Updated then I have to insert new record in another custom object(Price Driver Audit Log) specifying the details similar to the history. Like the parent Id, Action, Createdby and also few of the parent object records like AccountId. Below is the screenshot of a Proposal record .
[image: Proposal Record Sample]

Below is the Audit Log Sample.

[image: Audit Log Sample]

In **Audit Log Object** fields , For **Audit Event Name** I need the name of field which has been modified like "Account". In **Audit Event Notes** I need that "Changed Account from Tata Consultancy Services to Infosys Ltd".

I have written the below trigger but it has issues.

```
Trigger ProposalTrigger on Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c (After Insert, After Update) 
{
IF(Trigger.IsAfter)
{
    IF(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate)
    {
        ProposalTriggerOperations.ProposalAuditLog(Trigger.new);
    }
}}
```

Blow is the trigger class.

```
Public Class ProposalTriggerOperations
{
Public Static Void ProposalAuditLog(List<Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c> ProposalIds)
{ 
    List<Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c> PDALList  = new list<Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c>();

    DateTime dt = System.now();
    DateTime Earlier = dt.addSeconds(-5);
    system.debug('-----Time-----'+Earlier); -----Time-----2015-08-05 10:14:58

    List<Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__History> ListProposalHistory = [SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,Field,Id,ParentId FROM Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__History WHERE Field != 'Name' and ParentId=: ProposalIds and CreatedDate >=: Earlier];

    if(ListProposalHistory != NULL)
    {   
        for(Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__History APPH : ListProposalHistory)
        {
         //if(APPH.CreatedDate > Earlier)
            Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c PDAL = new Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c();                
            PDAL.Audit_Proposal__c = APPH.ParentId;
            PDAL.Audit_Event_Name__c = APPH.Field;
            //PDAL.Audit_Event_Notes__c = APPH.NewValue;
            PDALList.add(PDAL);
        }
        Insert PDALList;
    }
} }
```

Issues are:
1) It is not at all working when a new "Proposal" record is created.

2) It is working for updates when I am not giving the condition CreatedDate >=: Earlier , but for first update it creates 2 record(One for created and one for update), for second update it creates 3 records(one for created and 2 for updates) and so on. I need only 1 record to be inserted for each creation/updation.

3) I am unable to perform PDAL.Audit_Event_Notes__c = APPH.NewValue;. Error says "Invalid assignment from Sobject to string.

4)If I give the condition  CreatedDate >=: Earlier , then it does not work at all for both Insert/Update.

Please help me in achieving this functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any trigger in your post. Can you post your trigger please?

Comment: @Ruslan Vekua : Hello Ruslan, I have updated to add trigger.

Comment: very well-written post. Pleasure to read, hope it gets sorted soon!

Comment: What is the CreatedDate >=: Earlier condition purposes?

Comment: In point 2 I have mentioned that it was creating multiple records due to the SOQL query **SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,Field,Id,ParentId FROM Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__History WHERE Field != 'Name' and ParentId=: ProposalIds**. So to fetch only the recent History record I had provided this condition.